# Create a generic DB table

Tags: oracle, optimization, database-design, data-modeling

I am having multiple products and each of them are having there own Product table and Value table. Now I have to create a generic screen to validate those product and I don't want to create validated table for each Product. I want to create a generic table which will have all the Products details and one extra column called ProductIdentifier. but the problem is that here in this generic table I may end up putting millions of records and while fetching the data it will take time.

Is there any other better solution???

Comment: What do you mean by a value table. Can you share your existing and proposed table design

Comment: For one product there can be multiple values,.. so it is parent child relationship in product and value table.

Answer (score 0):

"Millions of records" sounds like a VLDB problem. I'd put the data into a partitioned table:

```
CREATE TABLE myproducts (
  productIdentifier NUMBER, 
  value1            VARCHAR2(30),
  value2            DATE
) PARTITION BY LIST (productIdentifier)  
( PARTITION p1 VALUES (1),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES (2),
  PARTITION p5to9 VALUES (5,6,7,8,9)
);
```

For queries that are dealing with only one product, specify the partition:

```
SELECT * FROM myproducts PARTITION FOR (9);
```

For your general report, just omit the partition and you get all numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM myproducts;
```

Documentation is here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/vldbg/toc.htm